# Solr query, at least one occurrence of phrase without another phrase before it

Tags: solr

How can I search for documents with phrases, where at least one occurrence of this phrase does not have a specific phrase before it?

To give an example, lets say I have three documents with the textfield as `text_en`

```
document 1 text: Oranges are tasty.

document 2 text: The color orange is bright, an orange is healthy.

document 3 text: The color orange.
```

I want all documents that mention oranges, except all of these occurances of orange in the document are preceded by "color".

The query should return documents 1 and 2. This is tricky in case of document 2, because there is an occurence of orange without "color" directly before it, so I want this document returned, eventhough "color orange" is also in this document. Document 3 should be not returned.

I tried to use [boolean queries with negations](http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/), but this of course excludes document 2:

```
q=textfield:"orange"&fq=NOT textfield:"color orange"
```

Can such a query as described above be done in Solr?

Comment: How about doing this in the analysis stage, write a customized tokenizer, which would remove `color orange` or change it to `colororange` before analyze it.

Comment: This "orange" example above is just an intuitive example for the general case, expressed by the first question. "How can I search for documents with phrases, where at least one occurrence of this phrase does not have a specific phrase before it?" So sadly it is not so simple.